# I'm trying to define a function in Google Colab but im getting this error: "name 'train_data' is not defined"

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

here is the code that im running, the version of the tensorflow is 2.6.0

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
X = tf.range(-100, 100, 4)
y = X + 10
# Split the data into train and test sets
X_train = X[:40] #first 40 are training samples
y_train = y[:40]

X_test = X[40:] # last 10 are testing samples
y_test = y[40:]
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
def plot_predictions(train_data=X_train,
                     train_labels=y_train,
                     test_data=X_test,
                     test_labels=y_test,
                     peredictions=y_pred):
  '''
  Plots training data, test data and compares predictions to ground truth labels.
  '''
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
# Plot training data in blue
plt.scatter(train_data, train_labels, c="b", labels="Training data")
# Plot testing data in green
plt.scatter(test_data, test_labels, c="g", labels="Testing data")
# Plot model's predictions in red
plt.scatter(test_data, predictions, c="r", labels="predictions")
# Show the legend
plt.legend();
```

and here is a screenshot from my code and the error in google colab:

[image]

Comment: Your indentation is not correct and you never call the function.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny what do you mean?? you mean that i need to delete the spaces?? but where?? could you please explain it more??

Comment: I can't tell what you want inside the function. Indentation is part of python's syntax. Everything that should be inside the function must be indented.

Comment: got it bro thanks. i just add a space before "plt.scatter" lines and it fixed.
i will put another Screenshot for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to the @MichaelSzczesny I did fix the code. it was needed a little space before the below lines. and the `labels="Training data"` was incorrect, the correct form is `label="Training data"`.
here is the correct and fixed code:

```
  plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
 # Plot training data in blue
  plt.scatter(train_data, train_labels, c="b", label="Training data")
 # Plot testing data in green
  plt.scatter(test_data, test_labels, c="g", label="Testing data")
 # Plot model's predictions in red
  plt.scatter(test_data, predictions, c="r", label="predictions")
 # Show the legend
  plt.legend();
```